# How to Export large Table with 1.2 billion rows from Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, datatable

I am trying to export a large table using

```
SELECT name1, name2, name3, name4 
From table1
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
```

However, after waiting for 1 hour, it returns OUT OF Memory DB connection needs to reset. I tried using the COPY table to csv file, but it returns needs to be superuser with STDIN/STDOUT. I am new to Postgresql.

How can I export this table without running out of memory?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to chunk it up, I don't see how it's going to process 1.2 billion lines without freaking out.

Have a script that does off 10000 at a time or something and saves the starting index for the next cycle.

Comment: thanks for the answer Ryan. I am currently searching if there is a way to pull data in chunks to 4 different files. For example - Pull 1/4 1/4 1/4 1/4 into 4 different csv. Lets see if that works

Answer (score 0):

Please read error messages carefully and convey them to us verbatim.  COPY says you need to be a superuser **unless** you use STDIN/STDOUT, not with them.

You should use a client-specific method to do this.  If your client is `psql` that would be [`\copy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY).  If your client is something else, you should tell us what that is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me check the docs for this. But is there a way - instead of pulling the data into 1 table. I can split the data and pull it into smaller chunks to different files?

Comment: You can export arbitrary queries by putting them in parenthesis, so you could divide it into chunks that way.  You might need to do it all in a REPEATABLE READ transaction so the data doesn't diverge between queries.  Or you could use the COPY/\copy feature of `TO PROGRAM` to pipe the output to `split` or whatever your favorite command is to split up files.